# Why wont this Python code pop/delete element from a list?

Tags: python

Python code:

```
PeoplesNames = []
while len(PeoplesNames) < 3:
    person = input('Enter your name: ')
    PeoplesNames.append(person)
print PeoplesNames
if 'Dan' in PeoplesNames:
    PeoplesNames.pop('Dan')
    print PeoplesNames
```

From my understanding this should run through the while loop (which it does) until the list hits length of 3 (which it does) then print the list (which it does) then hit the if statement and delete dan from the list and then print the new list (which it does not)
do i need to nest the if statement or something else?
thanks

Comment: look up the difference between `.remove()` and `.pop()` for lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: sorry yes it is remove that works

Comment: No `;` required in Python.

Comment: This should raise an exception which makes it clear on which line the error is. Are you just ignoring the exception?

Answer (score 2):

```
list.pop() #used to pop out the top of the stack(list) or

list.pop(index) #can be an index that needed to be pop out, but

list.remove(item) # removes the item specified
```

Try with the below solution

```
if 'Dan' in PeoplesNames:
        PeoplesNames.remove('Dan')
        print PeoplesNames
```

Comment: `list.pop` does take an argument; but it’s an index.

Answer (score 1):

or - keeping [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) in mind - you could:

```
PeoplesNames = [];
while len(PeoplesNames) < 3:
    person = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
    PeoplesNames.append(person)
print PeoplesNames
try:
    PeoplesNames.remove('Dan')
except ValueError:
    pass
print PeoplesNames
```

also note that in `python 2.7` you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.